# Error while loading shared libraries: foo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, debian, raspberry-pi3

I have cross compiled c++ code for raspberry pi.

Below is process i followed,

1 ) Cloned the official toolchain from raspberry pi github ( URL : https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools )
Set the environment variable of arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++ ( in .bashrc file )

3 ) Typed this command for generating binary for ARM architecture

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ./test.cpp -L. -lfoo -o test
```

4 ) Binary is successfully generated now. I tried to run the binary with below commands but had no luck with it.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/pi/Downloads/linux-sdk-demo-arm/foo.so ./test
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/linux-sdk-demo-arm ./test
```

even i set the environment variable in .bashrc file but having no luck

It gives the below errors respectively,

```
ERROR: ld.so: object './foo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
./test: error while loading shared libraries: foo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

AND

```
 ./test: error while loading shared libraries: foo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure the foo.so file is there at the right path but it can not find it.Here's the directory structure,

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi  15263 Jan  9 17:23 cp5200api.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1110 Mar  6 12:17 dtype.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 152751 Mar  9 13:43 foo.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi    512 Mar 12 08:42 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1285 Mar  8 20:13 notplugged
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   1285 Mar  8 20:13 plugged
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  13228 Mar 12 08:42 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   2204 Mar  6 15:22 test.cpp
```

Comment: What does `ldd foo.so` output?

Comment: It says " Not a dynamic executable "

Comment: So it's not a library then. Try `file foo.so`.

Comment: Try the full path instead of ./test

Comment: @csl foo.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

Comment: @VictorGubin Same error

Comment: @csl it runs on x86_64 GNU/Linux machine with the same .so file ( compiled for x86_64 )

Comment: @Aniket Ok, seems LD_LIBRARY_PATH not working for PI. Take a look into [guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) I.e. ldconfig -n test

Comment: @VictorGubin Yes tried all option including `ldconfig -n foo.so` and `ldconfig -v`. But having no luck

Comment: [ldconfig -n](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) for directories not files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166739/discussion-between-aniket-and-victor-gubin).